# Prove this polynomial falls within $\mathbb R[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

[ The problem below is from Yao Musheng (姚慕生), Wu Quanshui (吴泉水), *Advanced Algebra* (高等代数学) Ed $2$, Fudan University Press, page $207$. ]

> Suppose $f(x)\in \mathbb C[x]$. If $\forall c\in \mathbb R$, $f(c)\in\mathbb R$, prove:
>   $$f(x)\in \mathbb R[x].$$

My attempt is as follows:
For convenience I first specify that and $\deg f(x)\ge 2$ (otherwise it is easy to prove). Suppose $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_nx^n\notin \mathbb R[x]$ , then at least one of its coefficients, say $a_i$ is not real number. Therefore let $a_i=A+Bi$ where $B\ne 0$, and let $\tilde{f}(x):=f(x)-a_ix^i$.
If $\tilde{x}\ne 0$ and it satisfies $\tilde{f}(\tilde{x})=0$, then 
$$f(\tilde{x})=a_i\tilde{x}^i$$
If $\tilde{x}$ is real, then so is $\tilde{x}^i$. But $a_i$ is not real, thus $f(\tilde{x})=a_i\tilde{x}^i$ is not real. However, since $\tilde x\in\mathbb R$, $f(\tilde{x})$ must be real. Contradiction. Therefore $\tilde{x}$ cannot be real. Then I don't know how to proceed.
I have tried disproving the possibility of $\tilde{x}=0$ case because that doesn't seem to lead to anything. But I also failed.
Seems that I have got on the wrong track into a dead end. I am really struggling with this problem now. Could anybody drop a hint or help me out? Best regards.

Comment: $n=\deg f$, then we have $\forall k \in \{0,1,\dots,n\}:\ a_k=\displaystyle\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}\in \Bbb R$

Comment: I'm sure this is a dupe but searching for it probably will be difficult.

Comment: @BillDubuque From textbook, must've been asked somewhere before. But same with me, I didn't want to take much pain searching. And it turned out I'd made the right choice, see all those nice answers below  ;-)

Comment: Perhaps you should include the details of the textbook this is from (title, author, where it is located in the book, etc.) in the body of your question. This will make it easier for future users to search for it.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Thank you. Yeah I should have. It is from *Advanced Algebra* (高等代数学) ed 2, by Yao and Wu et al, in Chinese though.

Comment: @ArthurFischer Later I'll make a further edit containing this reference information  to my post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write $f(x) = u(x) + i\,v(x)$, with $u,v \in \mathbb R[x]$.

By hypothesis, $v(c)=0$ for all $c \in \mathbb R$. This means that $v=0$ because it has an infinite number of roots.

Comment: Nicest approach so far.

Comment: I like it, because it is purely algebraic and generalizes to any other field extension of infinite fields in the following way: Write $$f(x) = \sum_i b_if_i(x)$$ where $b_0=1, b_1, b_2 \dotsc$ is a vector space basis of the field extension. Then finish the proof the same way.

Comment: beautiful proof!

Comment: By the way, is it ok to push it even further? Say, if f(x) maps (n+1) distinct real numbers into $\mathbb R$, then f(x) must fall into $\mathbb R[x]$?

Comment: @Vim of course you can weaken hypotheses.

Answer (score 4):

There is another nice approach:

$f-f(0) = x \cdot h(x)$ with some polynomial $h$. We have $h(c) = \frac{f(c)-f(0)}{c} \in \mathbb R$ for all $c \in \mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$. By continuity we deduce $h(0) \in \mathbb R$, hence $h \in \mathbb R[x]$ by induction on the degree.

But then clearly $f = x \cdot h(x) + f(0) \in \mathbb R[x]$.

Comment: All your methods are extremely nice and very help! But I'm sorry that I can accept only one of them and I have to make a hard decision on which one to accept. So far I think @lhf 's is most beautiful and easiest to follow and I will accept his. Still yours are sincerely appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Show that all the higher derivatives of $f$ at 0 are real number ( just by first principle and it should be easy). Note that all coefficients can be obtained from them.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve this problem is to use Lagrange polynomials

Since $P$ takes real values at at least $n+1$ points, let $\alpha_0,\ldots,\alpha_n\in\mathbb R$ be such that $P(\alpha_i)\in \mathbb R$.

Lagrange interpolation tells us that $\displaystyle P=\sum_{k=0}^n P(\alpha_k)\prod_{j\neq k}\frac{X-\alpha_j}{\alpha_k-\alpha_j}$

Hence $P\in\mathbb R[X]$

This proof, as well as lhf's one shows that hypotheses may be weakened to "$P$ assumes real values at at least $\deg P +1$ real points (instead of the whole real line)".

Comment: Nice method! But I think maybe we can push even further (inspired by lhf's): what if $P$ assumes real values at at least $(n+1)$ distinct complex points? Provided we presume that $\deg P=n-1$, I think it'd be ridiculous if $P$ had some imaginary component.

Comment: Yes you're right, lhf's argument push it even further. He definitely has the nicest proof.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $f(x)$ is a polynomial with leading term $a_n x^n$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)/x^n = a_n$. So $a_n$ is real. Can you see how to proceed from there, subtracting off leading terms from $f$?

Comment: I have only learnt real number limit. Can I extend it naturally into $\mathbb C$ to show $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)/x^n = a_n$$?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using big hammers, you can use Schwarz reflection principle to conclude that $f(z)=\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ and the result follows by comparing coefficients.

Comment: This look like a quick-and-easy way! Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Is "comparing coefficients" ok here? Since $z$ seems to need to be specified before you put it into $f(\cdot)$.

Comment: $z$ is a complex variable here.

Comment: Oh yes.. I'm stupid .  So this one is really another brilliant approach!

Comment: Thanks. But my advice is to avoid big hammers as much as possible unless you run out of ideas. The other solutions here are nice, too.

Comment: I know it's best to avoid using big hammers. But isn't the reflection  (conjugation) principle here very natural? Why is it "big hammer"?